# Is it possible to styleRef a style, which is not legal style numbering, with legal style numbering?

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference

I have made a custom "Heading 1" style, look something like this for example:

Chapter`壹` (the 『壹』stands for "one" in Traditional Chinese, selected by the dropdown list, without checking 'Use Legal Style Numbering')

The problem when I try to use a styleRef, I want the caption text to be legal style numbering.

`Figure {STYLEREF 1 \s}-{SEQ figure \* ARABIC \s 1}` shows `壹-1`

But this is what I want: `1-1`

Comment: Try `{ STYLEREF 1 \s \*ARABIC }`.

Comment: Yeah I've tried it already. Not working :(

Comment: I would not be using StyleRef for this  but rather the Caption feature initially and then either a Table of Figures or a Cross-Reference to the Figure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with STYLEREF because although Word's field codes can generate that sequence in Chinese, they don't recognize the characters as numbers if you try to reformat them via *Arabic or #0 for example.

What you could do is use SEQ-based numbering for your chapter headings instead of automatic numbering, e.g.

```
Chapter { SEQ CHapter \*CHINESENUM2 } your chapter heading...
```

Then use a SEQ field in the captions instead of a STYLEREF field, e.g.

```
Figure { SEQ Chapter \c }-{ SEQ Figure \*Arabic \s \1 }
```

So you won't be able to use the Figure number insertion dialog either. But you can make an Autotext/Building block etc. from the text+fields and use that.

The ToC and a Table of Figures based on the "Caption" style (or whatever style you use for your Figure numbers) should work OK.